NG-ZORRO - Disable previous date
HTML:
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 form-group">
  <div class="label-mini">
    <span>Issue Date</span>
  </div>
  <nz-date-picker nzSize="large" nzPlaceHolder="Choose a date" formControlName="issue_date">
  </nz-date-picker>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 form-group">
  <div class="label-mini">
    <span>Delivery Date</span>
  </div>
  <nz-date-picker
    nzSize="large"
    nzPlaceHolder="Choose a date"
    formControlName="delivery_date"
    >
  </nz-date-picker>
</div>

ts:
initializeForm() {
  this.purchaseOrderForm = new FormGroup({        
    issue_date: new FormControl(new Date().toISOString()),
    delivery_date: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
      Validators.required,
    ])),
  });
}

I want to disable the previous date based on issue_date.
If issue_date is "05-05-2024", then on delivery_date it will disable the previous date of issue_date. If I change it, it will also work as disabling the previous date wise.
[n.b: issue_date default value is first time set as the current date, so the user can change it if the user needs but if not change it will set as the current date]

You can provide the [nzDisabledDate] with the function consists of disable date logic to your delivery_date date picker.
<nz-date-picker
  nzSize="large"
  nzPlaceHolder="Choose a date"
  formControlName="delivery_date"
  [nzDisabledDate]="disabledDeliveryDate"
>
</nz-date-picker>

disabledDeliveryDate = (date: Date): boolean => {
  let issueDate = this.purchaseOrderForm.controls.issue_date.value;
  if (!issueDate || !date) {
    return false;
  }

  return date.getTime() <= new Date(issueDate).getTime();
};

Demo @ StackBlitz

perfectly working but if i input delivery_date: 10-05-2024 then change issue_date to 12-05-2024. its an issue because issue_date date always less than delivery_date

In this case, you can subscribe to the valueChanges observable for issue_date control and set the delivery_date value to later than 1 day to avoid that delivery_date value is invalid. Or you can through this observable to pop out error message etc. Demo

You need to use the nzDisabledDate attribute and provide a function, that returns a boolean which determines if the date needs to be disabled/enabled. Working example below!
HTML
<nz-date-picker
    nzSize="large"
    nzPlaceHolder="Choose a date"
    formControlName="delivery_date" [nzDisabledDate]="disabledDate"
    >
</nz-date-picker>

TS
  disabledDate = (current: Date): boolean => {
    const issueDateCtrl = this.purchaseOrderForm.get('issue_date');
    const issueDateValue = issueDateCtrl?.value || null;
    // Can not select days before today and today
    return issueDateValue
      ? differenceInCalendarDays(current, new Date(issueDateValue)) < 0
      : false;
  };

FULL CODE:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { differenceInCalendarDays, setHours } from 'date-fns';

import { DisabledTimeFn, DisabledTimePartial } from 'ng-zorro-antd/date-picker';

@Component({
  selector: 'nz-demo-date-picker-disabled-date',
  template: `
  <form [formGroup]="purchaseOrderForm">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 form-group">
      <div class="label-mini">
        <span>Issue Date</span>
      </div>
      <nz-date-picker nzSize="large" nzPlaceHolder="Choose a date" formControlName="issue_date">
      </nz-date-picker>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 form-group">
      <div class="label-mini">
        <span>Delivery Date</span>
      </div>
      <nz-date-picker
        nzSize="large"
        nzPlaceHolder="Choose a date"
        formControlName="delivery_date" [nzDisabledDate]="disabledDate"
        >
      </nz-date-picker>
    </div>
</form>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      nz-date-picker,
      nz-range-picker {
        margin: 0 8px 12px 0;
      }
    `,
  ],
})
export class NzDemoDatePickerDisabledDateComponent {
  purchaseOrderForm = new FormGroup({
    issue_date: new FormControl(new Date().toISOString()),
    delivery_date: new FormControl(
      '',
      Validators.compose([Validators.required])
    ),
  });

  disabledDate = (current: Date): boolean => {
    const issueDateCtrl = this.purchaseOrderForm.get('issue_date');
    const issueDateValue = issueDateCtrl?.value || null;
    // Can not select days before today and today
    return issueDateValue
      ? differenceInCalendarDays(current, new Date(issueDateValue)) < 0
      : false;
  };
}

Stackblitz Demo
